# Why doesn't Telegram's desktop file show its name label in the Dash?

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash, .desktop, telegram

I've created a .desktop file for Telegram but it doesn't show the label like all others. I did the same with Android Studio and it worked perfectly. Here's what I typed within telegram.desktop :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram
Comment=Telegram
Exec=/usr/local/Telegram/Telegram
Icon=/usr/local/Telegram/telegram.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Messaging;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

just run telegram it will automatically create a telegramdesktop.desktop file as follows

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Telegram Desktop
Comment=Official desktop version of Telegram messaging app
#path file
Exec=/home/username/download/telegram/Telegram -- %u
Icon=telegram
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Telegram
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Comment: It's still not working. I've also tried to create a .desktop file by myself doing copy/paste of what you wrote and it doesn't work.
It keeps showing only the icon like the picture above